# How to bring JSON data to a Javascript table?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I’m trying to bring the data from a JSON file to the inputs of a table with Javascript, so that the same inputs can be editable from the table, but only get it to bring the last data from the JSON file (value 10 and rat10)I try with the other fields and he doesn’t bring them to me.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tshn3.png)
Parte del Script

```
const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open('GET', 'Datos/datos.json', true);
        xhttp.send();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                //console.log(this.responseText);
                let datos = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                // console.log(datos);
                for(let item of datos){
                    document.getElementById('valor').value = `${item.valor}`;       
                    document.getElementById('resultado').value = `${item.resultado}`;       
                    document.getElementById('valor5').value = `${item.valor5}`;     
                    document.getElementById('rat5').value = `${item.rat5}`;     
                    document.getElementById('valor10').value = `${item.valor10}`;
                    document.getElementById('rat10').value = `${item.rat10}`;
                }
            }
        }
```

JSON

```
[
    {"valor":"123","resultado":"2","resultado2":"61.5"},
    {"valor1":"34","rat1":"2","result":"17"},
    {"valor2":"12","rat2":"2","result2":"6"},
    {"valor3":"12","rat3":"4","resultado3":"3"},
    {"valor4":"23","rat4":"2","resultado4":"11.5"},
    {"valor5":"23","rat5":"4","resultado5":"5.75"},
    {"valor6":"21","rat6":"2","resultado6":"10.5"},
    {"valor7":"5","rat7":"7","resultado7":"0.7142857142857143"},
    {"valor8":"6","rat8":"3","resultado8":"2"},
    {"valor9":"23","rat9":"2","resultado9":"11.5"},
    {"valor10":"34","rat10":"4","resultado10":"8.5"}
]
```

Parte del HTML

```
<td rowspan="8" style="text-align: center; background-color: rgba(7, 129, 7, 0.705);"><form action="Datos/datos.php" id="formdata"><input
                    type="number" class="valor" id="valor" name="valor" ></form></td>
                     <td rowspan="8" style="text-align: center; background-color: rgba(216, 187, 22, 0.911);"><input
                        type="number" class="resultado" id="resultado" name="resultado" ></td>

<td style="text-align: center; background-color:  rgba(7, 129, 7, 0.705);"><Input type="number"
                    id="valor5" name="valor5" > </td> <td
                    style="text-align: center; background-color: rgba(216, 187, 22, 0.911);"><Input
                    type="number" id="rat5" name="rat5"></Input></td>


<tr>
                        <td>BALANCEADOR</td>
                        <td>F5</td>
                        <td>Virtual Server</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center; background-color:  rgba(7, 129, 7, 0.705);"><Input type="number"
                            id="valor10" name="valor10"></Input></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center; background-color: rgba(216, 187, 22, 0.911);"><Input type="number"
                        id="rat10" name="rat10"></Input></td>
                        <td><input type="number" id="resultado10" class="resultado" name="resultado10" readonly></td>
                    </tr>
```

[Image that only brings the last, I need after other data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tshn3.png)

Comment: Inside your `for` you are replacing the values from elements with id `resultado9`, `valor10` and `rat10` on every iteration.... Also if you are setting values, there's no need to create a variable like `let valor = ...` since you are not getting anything, just setting

Comment: My suggestion is, [edit] your question, post your HTML, try to create a [mcve]. Right now, looking to your logic, it makes little sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that you are hardcoding the selector and value names. Since the object keys are ids, and the values are values, then just make that assumption and iterate the result using them.

Like this:

```js
this.readyState = 4;
this.status = 200;
var responseText = `[{"valor":"123","resultado":"2","resultado2":"61.5"},
{"valor1":"34","rat1":"2","result":"17"},
{"valor2":"12","rat2":"2","result2":"6"},
{"valor3":"12","rat3":"4","resultado3":"3"},
{"valor4":"23","rat4":"2","resultado4":"11.5"},
{"valor5":"23","rat5":"4","resultado5":"5.75"},
{"valor6":"21","rat6":"2","resultado6":"10.5"},
{"valor7":"5","rat7":"7","resultado7":"0.7142857142857143"},
{"valor8":"6","rat8":"3","resultado8":"2"},
{"valor9":"23","rat9":"2","resultado9":"11.5"},
{"valor10":"34","rat10":"4","resultado10":"8.5"}
]`;

if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
  let datos = JSON.parse(responseText);
  datos.forEach(dt => Object.entries(dt).forEach(([k, v]) => {
    let el = document.querySelector("#" + k);
    if (el) el.value = v;
  }));
}
```

```html
<td rowspan="8" style="text-align: center; background-color: rgba(7, 129, 7, 0.705);">
  <form action="Datos/datos.php" id="formdata"><input type="number" class="valor" id="valor" name="valor"></form>
</td>
<td rowspan="8" style="text-align: center; background-color: rgba(216, 187, 22, 0.911);"><input type="number" class="resultado" id="resultado" name="resultado"></td>

<td style="text-align: center; background-color:  rgba(7, 129, 7, 0.705);">
  <Input type="number" id="valor5" name="valor5"> </td>
<td style="text-align: center; background-color: rgba(216, 187, 22, 0.911);">
  <Input type="number" id="rat5" name="rat5"></Input>
</td>


<tr>
  <td>BALANCEADOR</td>
  <td>F5</td>
  <td>Virtual Server</td>
  <td style="text-align: center; background-color:  rgba(7, 129, 7, 0.705);">
    <Input type="number" id="valor10" name="valor10"></Input>
  </td>
  <td style="text-align: center; background-color: rgba(216, 187, 22, 0.911);">
    <Input type="number" id="rat10" name="rat10"></Input>
  </td>
  <td><input type="number" id="resultado10" class="resultado" name="resultado10" readonly></td>
</tr>
```